# Is there a way to return a value instead of blank for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I am trying to do a HTML table but i am having troubles where it does not return a value.
This example shows my result.[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwgSe.png)

Is it possible to script that if there isnt any result, it will return 0?

I tried `ISNULL` method and it does not return me any values.

I am expecting that by using the `ISNULL` method, it will return a 0  in the result, but it doesn't do so.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(body, 0) 
FROM
    [EMAIL_MATRIX] 
WHERE
    body NOT IN (SELECT c.Body
                 FROM [dbo].[EMAIL_DETAILS] a
                 INNER JOIN [Email_matrix] c ON SUBSTRING(a.Subject, 5, LEN(a.Subject) - 4) = c.Subject
                                             AND a.Body LIKE CONCAT('%', c.body, '%') 
                 WHERE CAST(a.Send AS DAte) = '2022-10-04')
```

Comment: we can't possibly answer this question without seeing the sql you are using

Comment: hi @Hogan I have added the code. Sorry as I am a first time user

Comment: Use standard SQL: `SELECT COALESCE(body, '0')`.  body is clearly some kind of text field, so you should return a text value, to replace a `NULL`.  However, your output is showing no rows at all.  That strongly suggests, that there are no values that match your `WHERE`.  I advise you to run the inner SQL - `SELECT c.body` etc separately to check the values returned.

Comment: FYI -- the ISNULL in your query does nothing, there is no case that field will be null, but your problem is there are no rows returned, @gotqn shows you how to solve that in his answer.

Comment: Hi @Hogan, I tried gotqn solution but it still returns me a NULL value.

Comment: I didn't post a solution.  Do you mean gotqn's solution?  That solution is supposed to return a null value.  What results are you expecting?  Please update your question to clearer about what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    Select ISNULL(body,0) AS body
    from [EMAIL_MATRIX] 
    where body NOT IN
    (
        SELECT c.Body
        FROM [dbo].[EMAIL_DETAILS] a
        INNER JOIN [Email_matrix] c 
            ON SUBSTRING(a.Subject,5,LEN(a.Subject)-4) = c.Subject
            and a.Body LIKE CONCAT('%', c.body, '%') 
        where Cast(a.Send as DAte) = '2022-10-04'
    )
)
SELECT body
FROM DataSource
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DataSource)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DataSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Select REPLACE(ISNULL(body,0),'',0) from [EMAIL_MATRIX] 
where body NOT IN(
SELECT c.Body
FROM [dbo].[EMAIL_DETAILS] a
INNER JOIN [Email_matrix] c 
ON SUBSTRING(a.Subject,5,LEN(a.Subject)-4) = c.Subject
 and a.Body LIKE CONCAT('%', c.body, '%') 
where Cast(a.Send as DAte) = '2022-10-04')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried and it still returns the same result.

Comment: The problem is not with the value in the column the issue is no results are found in the query